# Some browsers stop loading my webpage at random

Tags: javascript, caching, video, browser, load

I built a website to collect data from people concerning 300 six-second movie clips. How it works: After seeing each clip, they answer a question below the video, click "Next" to move on to the next video, and so on.

Problem: While I can run the whole thing on my browser (Safari 7.0.1) seamlessly, some people say their browser stops "loading" the videos after a certain time (some say after seeing 70 videos, others say after seeing 200 videos...). Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? Here's a sample from the code -- I deleted the questions themselves, but am keeping the part where I load the videos successively:

Thank you!

```
<script>

var currentPage = 0;
var numberOfVideos = videoList.length; // videoList contains names of all 300 movie clips.

function NextTrial() {
        var k = currentPage;
        $("#page" + k).hide();
        k++;
        $("#page" + k).show();
        // use dynamic loading (as below) to avoid crashing the browser.
        $(".replaceVideo", "#page" + currentPage).replaceWith('<video id="video' + k + '"><source src=' + video[k] + '.mov type="video/mp4"/></video></div>');
}


for (var i=0;i<numberOfVideos;i++) {   
   document.write('<div class="page" id="page' + i + '">');
   document.write('<p class="replaceVideo"></p>');
   document.write('<a href="javascript:NextTrial()"> <p> Next Trial </p> </a>');
   document.write('</div>');
}

</script>
```

Comment: What error do you see in the console when this happens? Do you look at the NETWORK panel to see if the resources are loading properly?

Comment: You do realize you're just overriding each `document.write()`, don't you?

Comment: currentPage always stays `0`. If you are using jQuery, why not create all your `#page-x`es with jQuery?

Comment: I'm a complete newbie, @RUJordan, could you be more specific? (also, the code is doing what I want it to be doing, and is properly collecting data -- until it crashes on some computers but not others)

Comment: would that help the loading of the videos, @juk?